# How can i display a jquery slide on front page

Tags: php, jquery, slideshow

Hy, I integrate a jquery slide on front page, the problem apear when i install Next Gen Galley on the website. The Slide Stop Working, there is a conflict i think.

I have 2 header

index-header.php - the header of index page
Slide

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
// ---------------------------------------------------
// Slideshow 1
    $('#slideshow_1').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',       
        easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
        speed:  700, 
        timeout: 5000, 
        pager: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_paging', 
        prev: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_prev',
        next: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_next',
        before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {
            var data = $('.data', $(nextSlideElement)).html();
            $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').remove();
                $('<div class="data">'+data+'</div>').hide().appendTo('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box').fadeIn(700);
            });
        }
    });
    // not using the 'pause' option. instead make the slideshow pause when the mouse is over the whole wrapper
    $('.ss1_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#slideshow_1').cycle('pause');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#slideshow_1').cycle('resume');
    });
// ---------------------------------------------------
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); // for this demo disable all links that point to "#"
    });
});
</script>
```

header.php - it is use on every page of the site.
here i have `<?php wp_head(); ?>`

How can i make it work.
How can i load the slide without interfering the Next Gen Galley jquery

Comment: Try to remove the JQuery call (first line).

Comment: removing that brake's the site.. the 4 slide images are apearing each under

Comment: maybe you can give a URL to see the page online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jerome mentioned in his comment, including your own version of jQuery via a script tag is wrong. Nextgen adds the WordPress supplied version correctly via [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), which creates the conflict.

1. Remove the inclusion of jQuery via script tag.
2. Properly [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your other javascript files with jQuery as a dependency.
3. Fix your jQuery code to work in [noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Comment: removing wp-head code solve my problem, i have 2 header's, i have a static page in front.

Thank's for that.

Comment: Removing `wp_head()` will inevitably lead to all sorts of other breakage.